# Element in fixed-positioned DIV not clickable randomly

Tags: html, css, svg, css-position, onclicklistener

For a mobile sticky menu I use the following code (shortened):

```
<nav class="navigation--wrapper">
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="navigation--hamburger js--hamburger">
            <svg>
                ...
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation--mobile is-content-menu js--mobile-navigation">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

With the following (shortened) CSS-styles:

```
.navigation--wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 0;
}

.navigation {
    height: 50px;
}

.navigation--hamburger {
    float: left;
    padding: 14px;
}

.navigation--mobile {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.navigation--mobile.is-open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I added an event listener to the div that wraps the hamburger-icon (`js--hamburger`) which toggles the menu by adding `is-open` class to `js--mobile-navigation`.
This works perfectly most of the time but after a random number of clicks, the button stops working.

I added an event listener for all clicks in the document and logged the target to the console:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    return console.log(event.target);
});
```

Now for the clicks where the menu appears, it always shows a part of the svg as target which is just fine. After a few times of clicking (randomly, sometimes also at the first time) the menu is not working an the the div with class `js--mobile-navigation` is shown as target and the menu stops working until I reload the page.

I think this must be a bug with fixed-positioned elements. This Problem occurs in all major browsers on desktop, tablet and mobile.

Comment: set https://jsfiddle.net/ of your sample code.

Comment: have you tried that in other browsers?? might be a problem with the browser you are using..